# Finding neighbors in a game of five-in-a-row

Tags: javascript

I can declare a winner if a player gets five of their tokens in a row, and now I am trying to implement the feature of capturing an opponent's pieces. For example, I am player X, I can trap O's pieces like this X00X in any direction on the board. In order to implement this, is the following logic correct:
Find all neighbors around O, check and see if the neighbor is an X or an O, if there are two 0's in a row surrounded by an X on each side, I can take those pieces. Is there a better way to approach this problem? I am thinking of something like this:

```
function isOCaptured(token, row, col){
   if(gameBoard[row][col]==="O" && gameBoard[row][col+1] === "X"
      && gameBoard[row][col-1] === "X"){
    return true;    
   }
   return false;
}
```

But it does not seems to return true when I place one O in between two X's.

Here is what my `server.js` and `app.js` look like right now: https://jsfiddle.net/Amidi/s3gnx3rL/4/ The HTML is just a 13 x 13 grid of buttons with an event attached to each which sends the buttons coordinates to the add() function in my `app.js`

Comment: Can we get a jsfiddle or picture of the game? It would be easier to visualize the problem you have.

Comment: Okay, I updated my question with a link to my jsfiddle.

Comment: Can you add the html to the jsfiddle as well?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Amidi/s3gnx3rL/8/ I know I shouldn't be using the inline onclick feature but I will optimize it later on.

Comment: The code above looks like it should work. The problem might be somewhere else. How are you using the function? (On a side note, this is not the same function as in your fiddle)

Comment: I think I forgot to update the fiddle with the above changes to my function. I am using the function inside a socket.on event. I get the coordinates from the client, var x = data.x, y = data.y, t = data.token; the I test it inside this socket.on event like this if(isOCaptured(x,y)===true){console.log("y is between 2 x\s");

Comment: The function as written above takes 3 arguments. When you're calling it, you are giving it 2 arguments. (No, that wouldn't result in an error. Isn't weak typing lovely?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, the problem seems to be that the code only works if the "O" was placed last. This can be solved with a for-loop.

```
for(var i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
    if (gameBoard[row][col+i]==="O" && gameBoard[row][col+i+1] === "X"
        && gameBoard[row][col+i-1] === "X") {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

You can also use a slice:

```
// The closest 5 cells to the left/right of the newly added piece, as a string
var str = gameBoard[row].slice(col-2,col+3).join("");
// Look for the pattern "XOX" in those 5 cells. Double negation to return bool.
return !!str.match("XOX");
```

---

## Old answer

According to your comment, the code was called like this:

```
if(isOCaptured(x,y)===true){console.log("y is between 2 x\s");
```

This means that the function is called with two instead of three arguments. That will result in the following values of the arguments: `token = x`, `row = y` and `col = undefined`.

The expression being evaluated will thus be:

```
gameBoard[y][undefined]==="O" && gameBoard[y][undefined+1] === "X"
  && gameBoard[y][undefined-1] === "X"
```

Which would evaluate as follows:

1. Evaluating `gameBoard[y]` will succeed, resulting in a column (the wrong one though).
2. Then we try indexing the column with `undefined`, and since the array doesn't contain an element called `undefined`, it will fail, resulting in (again) `undefined`.
3. Then we compare this value `undefined` with `"0"`, which is obviously false.
4. The expression `false && ...` will return `false`, as will the whole function.

If the second part would have been executed, it would calculate `undefined+1`, which is (quite accurately) evaluated to `NaN` (not a number). The array doesn't contain `NaN` either, so this calculation would evaluated to false as well.

---

Now, for some advice:

1. The statement `if(expr){return true} else {return false}` can be simplified to just `return expr`.
2. These kinds of bugs are pretty easy to find if you use the Chrome Debugger (or Firebug for firefox), where you can step through the code and see exactly what happens and where stuff goes wrong.

Comment: I redefined the parameters to just take in two arguments: the row, and col. I noticed some odd behavior. I am checking to see if an O is in between two X's. My function returns true only if two X's are first placed and then I place an O in between them (which is not what I want). It should return true if I have an X placed, then an O, then an X, right? Basically, if two O's are in a row, I want to be able to trap them by placing an X on each side.

Comment: I really like that slice version. How to extend it so it searches not only left to right, but also top to bottom, and both diagonal directions for 'XOX' pattern?

Comment: @BeeBop It's not as easy to do it in the other directions, but try figuring out how it works, and you might be able to figure out how to extend it yourself. If you are still confused after giving it an honest attempt, please feel free to ask further, more specific questions about it. (I'm glad to help, but I'm not here to write your code for you.)